# Migrating to play 2.2, correct usage of Action.asyc

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am in the process of trying to upgrade Play Framework from 2.1 to 2.2 and are running into difficulties with the new Action.asyc syntax. An example problem

I get:

```
   ->Action.async { 
   type mismatch; found : play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] 
   required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult]
```

After lots of Google, am switching to the SO community. Example code passage (lots of irrelevant detail stripped out) here:

**Play 2.1**

```
def homeContent(origin: String, segment: String) = Secured {
Action {
  implicit request =>
    val maybeOrigin = Origin.allOrigins.find(p => p.slug == origin)
    maybeOrigin match {
      case None => NotFound
      case Some(originPlace) => {

          val futureResult = scala.concurrent.Future {
            DealCard.getTopDealCardsFor(origin, segment)
          }
          Async {
            futureResult.map {
              case (topDeals) =>
                Ok(“”).as("application/json")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**Play 2.2.2**

```
  def homeContent(origin: String, segment: String) = Secured {
   Action.async {
  implicit request =>
    val maybeOrigin = Origin.allOrigins.find(p => p.slug == origin)
    maybeOrigin match {
      case None => Future.successful(NotFound)
      case Some(originPlace) => {
          Action.async {
            val futureResult = scala.concurrent.Future {
              DealCard.getTopDealCardsFor(origin, segment)
            }
            futureResult.map {
              case (topDeals) =>
                Ok("").as("application/json")
            }
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote an example app that might be helpful on [my Github](https://github.com/kaeawc/play-secured-action-builder).  The main idea is laid out below:

Normal actions in Play either expect an Action or a SimpleResult

```
def normal = Action { Ok("") }
```

Secured, the way you have it implemented, is expecting an Action

```
def secured = Secured { Action { Ok("") } }
```

And Action.async expects a Future of a SimpleResult, but still returns an Action

```
def async = Action.async { Future { Ok("") } }
```

What you seem to be looking for is a Secured that takes a Future[SimpleResult].  To do that you should try to follow the example laid out in the [Play documentation for Action Composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition) for

```
trait Security {

    class AuthenticatedRequest[A](val username: String, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

    object Secured extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {
      def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
        request.session.get("username").map { username =>
          block(new AuthenticatedRequest(username, request))
        } getOrElse {
          Future.successful(Results.Forbidden)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to compose something like this:

```
def securedAsync = Secured.async { Future { Ok("") } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Action.async` is within another `Action` block.  Your overall block needs to be `Action.async` within which you'll return a `Future` of a `Result`, e.g., `Ok`, `NotFound`, etc.

edit: This is what you're supposed to do:

```
def homeContent(origin: String, segment: String) = Secured {
   Action.async { implicit request =>
    val maybeOrigin = Origin.allOrigins.find(p => p.slug == origin)
    maybeOrigin match {
      case None => Future.successful(NotFound)
      case Some(originPlace) => {              
        DealCard.getTopDealCardsFor(origin, segment) map { topDeals =>
          Ok("").as("application/json")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the second Action.async is returning a: play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] rather than a scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult]. What's confusing is that the Ok() should be a Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult]. If I wrap it in a Future.successful it complains of overload on Async ((scala.concurrent.Future[scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult]])).

Comment: edited the question to clarify where I am having trouble. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how `Action.async` works in 2.2.  It's not like the old `Async` block that you just wrapped around a `Future`, it replaces the entire action.  They should not be nested.